# Use visual basic and c++/c# in tandem

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net

Quick question. I am developing a visual object recognition system in c++/c# as a class which needs to be used in a VB program. Is there any way to utilize c++code from VB? I.E. call methods, return variables, etc.

Thanks,
Kidovate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C++ component is a COM object there is no issue. When you say "c++/c#", those are worlds apart, if it it C# then vb will see it natively, otherwise you will need to do some COM interop.

Comment: So, I can build something in c# and have it work natively with VB? How?

Comment: depends on the VB. Are you using VB.net or VB6?

Comment: @Christian You can mix and match the code within the same solution. To test this: 1) Create a new empty solution. 2) Add a C# class library project to the solution. 3) Add a VB.NET class library (or console, or whatever you wish). 4) Add a project reference to your C# library from your VB project. Bang that is all there is to it. Remember, under the hood all of the assemblies are compiled to IL, so they really are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to utilize c++ cli which is a full blow .net language and can let you leverage both native c++ and .net.